# Is it possible to run a sub-grammar inside a grammar nqp?

Tags: regex, raku, nqp

If I have `Grammar a` and define a `Grammar b` that have a block '{ ... }' that has syntax of `Grammar a`, is it possible to somehow link these grammars together? I.e. `Grammar a` is Tcl and `Grammar b` is embedded C. How does Rakudo do this when switching from Perl6 grammar to Regex grammar?

Comment: What's nqp got to do with this question? Are you talking about grammars in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use Liz's-Answer;

answer Mine { ... }
say ?Mine if prompt 'Does that answer your question?' eq 'n' ;

answer Mine is B does Or-Perhaps-This does Or-Perhaps-That { }

role Or-Perhaps-This {
   token baz { <Liz's-Answer::B::foo> }
}

role Or-Perhaps-That {
   https://repl.it/@RalphMellor/Simple-slang
}
```

## `Liz's-Answer`

Liz's initial answer wisely started at the beginning: declaring that a Raku grammar/role has one or more of its rules textually declared in another Raku grammar/role.

But then you edited your question to add:

> I.e. Grammar `a` is Tcl and Grammar `b` is embedded C.

It's pretty unlikely that it would make sense for grammars for c and tcl to textually share any rules. :)

## `Or-Perhaps-This`

Another possibly relevant solution is to have a method within a grammar call another one in some other class. This can include a rule in one grammar calling a rule in another grammar.

This *could* be what you want for a tcl grammar/parser calling a c grammar/parser, or vice-versa, or both:

```
grammar c { ... }

grammar tcl {
    rule TOP { ... }
    ...
    rule block { 'c {' <c::TOP> '}' }
    ...
}

grammar c {
    rule TOP { ... }
    ...
    rule block { 'tcl {' <tcl::TOP> '}' }
    ...
}
```

## `Or-Perhaps-That`

> How does Rakudo do this when switching from Perl6 grammar to Regex grammar?

The above `Or-Perhaps-This` example kept things simple. It hard coded the call from tcl to c, and vice-versa, and did not add any "userland" code that tracked that a switch had occurred.

What if one wanted to:

- Have an arbitrary collection of languages calling into each other using the above `Or-Perhaps-This` technique;
- Be able to replace or tweak any grammar in the collection;
- Be able to add a new one (in conjunction with replacing/modifying an existing one to call the new one);
- Dynamically track precisely which grammar one is "in", in a dynamic/innermost sense, at any given time?

Also, what about that being the approach adopted for Raku itself, using its own grammar construct to define itself as a [braid](https://preview.tinyurl.com/raku-braid) of languages?

This is indeed the approach adopted for Raku, and, in turn, nqp, via a feature called "slangs", short for "sub-languages".

## Slangs

While the Raku implemented in Rakudo is actually constructed using slangs, they are *not* an official feature. I'm sure they will be one day but it could easily be years.

In the meantime, I think the best I can provide is:

- [The repl.it example](https://repl.it/@RalphMellor/Simple-slang).
- A link to [SO's matching "[raku] slang"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+slang).
- Friendly advice: liberally apply the compiler optimization flag [`-Ofun`](https://raku.org/fun/) as you spelunk the compiler's code and maybe use Comma on Rakudo to figure out what's going on...

Comment: The %*LANG seem to be involved somehow. I'm digging around in In rakudos src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp and  Perl6::Grammar::TOP adds self.define_slang(). But I cannot really follow how thethis works. Is there some NQP description somewhere? (ps also: how do you create a raku file at repl.it? )

Comment: "how do you create a raku file at repl.it?" Try [https://repl.it/languages/raku](https://repl.it/languages/raku). Hopefully that'll work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Grammars are really classes.  So you can inherit from them.  Or you can create a role and `does` that in both Grammars.

```
role A {
   token foo { bar }
}
grammar B does A {
    ...  # other stuff
}
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly. What I meant is i.e. Grammar a is tcl and Grammar b is a embedded C block. Will update the text